# Prompt for Permissions with Facebook PHP

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have a situation where a user might have authenticated my app for basic access, but on some pages I want to take advantage of the new Open Graph API and be able to publish actions onto their wall. So I'm trying to check if they have given my website this permission, and if they haven't give them an option to add that permission. Here's my code:

```
<?php
require 'fbphp/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '??????',
  'secret' => '???????',
));

$permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions");
if( array_key_exists('publish_actions', $permissions['data'][0]) ) {
    // Permission is granted!
    echo "we have permission";
} else {
    // We don't have the permission
    echo "no perms";
     $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'publish_actions' ) );
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
}

?>
```

What this code is currently doing is when I click the login link it redirects straight back to the same page without prompting for permissions (possibly because I am already technically logged in?). Of course I still haven't got the permission so I'm back at square one.

So how can I prompt for permissions for someone who is already logged in? I'm using test users created in the app roles if that has any bearing

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. But in my case, before i publish the site i test everything, like you are doing, so, try this. Go to the test user account on Facebook itself. Then go to Account Settings and then App Settings (which is on the left bar). Remove your site or app from there, so you will be removing its permissions. Then try to access your app again, it will now prompt for the new permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I later found out that wasn't my problem. It was because I'm requesting the publish_actions permissions which isn't available until Timeline/ Open graph comes out of beta. If I try other permissions I get prompted OK